# How can i delete contact from main AddressBook when i delete specific group in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, abaddressbooksource

i want to delete the group on addressBook. i have try this code it is successfully delete the group but on main addressBook contact are not deleted.

```
CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

    ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef newGroup;

    newGroup = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(iPhoneAddressBook,groupId);
    ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newGroup, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook,&error);
```

my requirement is i have one service to call every time when application is open i have get contact from service in a specific group. so i have delete old group and add new contact which is provide from service but it will twice the contact on main AddressBook because it will only delete group. i want to delete group as well as this group contact are delete on main addressBook both.

Finally my question is... How can i delete the group and group contact from main AddressBook please help me... Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Do this

```
-(void)RemoveContactGroup:(NSString *)name {
BOOL flag = [self CheckIfGroupExistWithName:name];

if(!flag)
{
    return;
}
CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef newGroup;
//if Existing Group

newGroup = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(iPhoneAddressBook,groupId);
NSArray *member = (__bridge NSArray *)ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(newGroup);
int nPeople = (int)[member count];

if (nPeople>0)
{
    for (int i=0; i<nPeople; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge  ABRecordRef)member[i];
        ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, (ABRecordRef)contactPerson, &error);
    }
}
ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, NULL);
CFRelease(newGroup);
}
```

First you can check the group are exist or not if exist give the group id

```
-(BOOL)CheckIfGroupExistWithName:(NSString*)groupName {

hasGroup = NO;
//checks to see if the group is created ad creats group for HiBye contacts
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook);
CFArrayRef groupLists= ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

for (int i=0; i<groupCount; i++) {
    ABRecordRef currentCheckedGroup = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groupLists, i);
    NSString *currentGroupName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(currentCheckedGroup);

    if ([currentGroupName isEqualToString:groupName]){
        //!!! important - save groupID for later use
        groupId = ABRecordGetRecordID(currentCheckedGroup);
        hasGroup=YES;
    }
    CFRelease(currentCheckedGroup);
}

if (hasGroup==NO){
    //id the group does not exist you can create one
}
return hasGroup;
}
```

Check It.